# UIButton addTarget method can not use in IOS 4.2

Tags: ipad, ios4, uibutton, target

i have a UIButton made programmatically and i want to add the target and the action for that button. i have use method `addTarget: action: forControlEvents:`

in IOS 4.1 this method is detected, but in 4.2 it didn't, here is my code

```
UIButton *moreButton = [[[UIButton alloc] init] autorelease];

float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]; 
    if(version <= 4.1){
        moreButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6.3+5*widthSegment, 0.0, widthSegment, heightSegment)];
        [moreButton addTarget:self action:@selector(getPopOverMore:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    else{
        //version 4.2
        NSLog(@"versi 4.2");
        moreButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        moreButton.frame = CGRectMake(6.3+7*widthSegment, 0.0, widthSegment, heightSegment);
        [moreButton addTarget:self action:@selector(getPopOverMore:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
```

and this is the action method :

```
- (IBAction)getPopOverMore:(id)sender{

if(moreFileController == nil) {

    moreFileController = [[MoreFilePopController alloc]
                          initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

    moreFileController.delegate = self;

    moreFilePopOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                 initWithContentViewController:moreFileController];
}

CGRect frameMore = CGRectMake(6.3+5*widthSegment, 0.0, widthSegment, heightSegment);


[moreFilePopOverController presentPopoverFromRect:frameMore inView:navBar 
                         permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

}

any body know, what's wrong here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work. also the initWithFrame for <=4.1 is unnecessary. i hope you are adding the button as a subview somewhere after this code.

try placing a breakpoint inside`- (IBAction)getPopOverMore:(id)sender{`

Comment: yes..it should work, and the wrong of this code is I was use UIButton as the global variable but i didn't alloc it. I'm really forget that. Now, i've solved the problem, and  i have edit my code above. Thank you for answer Gopal

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to put `IBAction` on `UIButton` sets manually.

```
[moreButton addTarget:self action:@selector(getPopOverMore:)       
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

You need to declare in your file.m:

-(void)getPopOverMore:(id)sender{
}
```